# how to remove parantheses and string from a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, split

Literally, I've been trying to a way to solve this but it seems that I'm poor on regex;)

I need to remove `(WindowsPath` and `)"`from the strings in a list

```
     x= ["(WindowsPath('D:/test/1_birds_bp.png'),WindowsPath('D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png'))", "(WindowsPath('D:/test/2_reptiles_bp.png'),WindowsPath('D:/test/2_crocodile_mp.png'))"]
```

So I tried

```
 import re
 cleaned_x = [re.sub("(?<=WindowsPath\(').*?(?='\))",'',a) for a in x]
```

outputs

```
["(WindowsPath(''),WindowsPath(''))", "(WindowsPath(''),WindowsPath(''))"]
```

what I need to have is;

```
cleaned_x= [('D:/test/1_birds_bp.png','D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png'), ('D:/test/2_reptiles_bp.png','D:/test/2_crocodile_mp.png')]
```

basically tuples in a list.

Comment: Why use `re` when every string starts with `( WindowsPath (...))` wouldn't it be easy to use slicing?

Comment: just curious - is there a need to use regexp's if you just want to remove them (and they are fixed substrings you want removed right)?  couldn't you use standard string replace() function?

Comment: @Richard anything that gives the expected result would work for me;)

Comment: ...actually I looked again, I think you do need to use regexp. ...hang on a sec :D

Comment: @Richard You guys are excellent help! Thanks for your time and efforts! This is a wonderful community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `re.findall` like this:

```
>>> cleaned_x = [tuple(re.findall(r"[A-Z]:/[^']+", a)) for a in x]
>>> cleaned_x
[('D:/test/1_birds_bp.png', 'D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png'), ('D:/test/2_reptiles_bp.png', 
'D:/test/2_crocodile_mp.png')]
>>>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use capturing groups? For instance:

```py
import re

re_winpath = re.compile(r'^\(WindowsPath\(\'(.*)\'\)\,WindowsPath\(\'(.*)\'\)\)$')

def extract_pair(s):
    m = re_winpath.match(s)
    if m is None:
        raise ValueError(f"cannot extract pair from string: {s}")
    return m.groups()

pairs = list(map(extract_pair, x))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appriciate for the flow!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take,

not pretty, and I did it in two steps so as not to make regexp spagetti, and you could turn it into a list comprehension if you like, but it should work

```
for a in x:
    a = re.sub('(\()?WindowsPath', '', a)
    a = re.sub('\)$','', a)
    print(a)
```